# How to get a substring from bash command

Tags: command-line, bash

Given the following substring given obtained from the command `df /dev/sdb1 | tail -n 1` :

`/dev/sdb1         1952971772 1441131032  511840740  74% /media/kaiman/ShareData`

I'd like to extract `1952971772` and `74%` from that string, to use it in a bash script.

I know I could use some cut commands or something, but it won't work anymore if a size changes, for example.

I also had thoughts about using a regex or something, but I'd like to have the most recommended approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about the general case, or about `df` in particular? If the latter, you can specify particular output fields explicitly e.g. `df --output=pcent /dev/sdb1`

Comment: You are using `cut` on character position on line which makes it fail when line length changes with fluctuations in file size. I believe you can tell `cut` to select column `2` and column `5` delineated by spaces but I'm on phone and can't research and effectively post an answer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Number of spaces may vary, so it's hard to tell which column-number is correct. `cut` will see one column after each delimiter.

Comment: Two or more contiguous spaces still count as a single space for delineating columns I think

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix correct :) I the commands from a text file I have  at hand :D

Comment: Duplicate of [Extract substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash)

Comment: @Rinzwind You try writing an answer here with a so-called smartphone that is really an oxymoron. Anyway you tempted me to quit my job to post answers here on laptop during business hours to catch you in points but then again how would I eat :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ df /dev/sdb1 | awk '{ print $5 }' | tail -n 1
```

for the percentage and

```
$ df /dev/sdb1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | tail -n 1
```

for the size.

Without the `tail`:

```
df /home | awk 'NR==2 { print $2 }'
df /home | awk 'NR==2 { print $5 }'
```

---

- `awk '{ print $2 }'`
  gets the 2nd column where multiple separators count as 1. So the 2nd column is always the same for your system for the 1st part of the command.
- `NR` gives you the total number of records being processed or the line number.

Comment: Or if you need both in one line `df /home | awk '{print $2; print $5;}'`.

Comment: Awk keeps the last line in the `END` block so instead of using `tail` just use `awk 'END { print $2,$5}'`

Comment: FYI I name dropped you in Meta :) https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18584/how-do-ask-op-to-reconsider-accept-answer-and-award-yours

Answer (score 8):

### Edited answer

As @kevin stated, you can use `awk` to select only the last line and avoid using tail at all by using `END` and also if you want to print two columns at once you can do this:

```
df /dev/sdb1 | awk 'END {print $2,$5}'
1952971772 74%
```

---

### Original answer

You can select the 2nd columns only:

```
$ df /dev/sdb1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' 
1952971772
```

Where `$2` indicates the position of TAB separated columns. You can use `cut` because it handle only one occurrence of TAB and here there are multiples TABs to delimita a column.

Comment: Awk keeps the last line in the `END` block so instead of using `tail` just use `awk 'END { print $2,$5}'`